# How to use custom reasteasy instead of jboss standard one

Tags: maven, jboss, resteasy

I am working with jboss 6.2 that has resteasy standard version set to 2.3.7.

I need to use resteasy 3.0.8 and currently I am trying to achieve this result using maven and specifying that version in the pom, the correct resteasy is put in the war but seems like jboss keeps on using 2.3.7.

I am wondering if I am following the right path and if somebody can provide me some web resources to solve my issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue.

This [link](http://www.java-adventures.com/jee/2014/07/01/jboss-eap6-upgrade-to-resteasy3x/) could be usefull, it works great for me.